# Internal render stuck at Freestyle View Map Creation

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I am using the freestyle effect in Blender internal and when I preview it, the effect gets rendered really quickly, but when I render the image for real, it always gets stuck on 'Freestyle: view map creation'.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: removing all cloth simulations and forces fixes the problem. So for stills, this is easily resolved, but for animations I have yet to find a solution.